# How to sort in Mongo Spring @Aggreation?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have

```
 @Aggregation({
        "{'$match': {'$and': [ { 'xId' : ?0 },{'pDay': { '$gte': ?1 } },{'pDay': { '$lte': ?2 } }, ] } }",
        "{'$sort': {'x2': 1,'x3': 1}}",
        "{$group: { _id: $pDay, abcs: { $addToSet : $$ROOT }}}",
        "{'$limit': ?4}",
        "{'$skip': ?5}"
})
```

but as result I see one record with abcs list, but items in in are unsorted by x2.

Sames is for sort after group.

```
public class XView {
    @Id
    Long pDay;
    List<X> abcs;
}
@Document
public class X {
    String xId; 
    String x2; 
    String x3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$group` does not preserve the order.

```
 @Aggregation({
        "{'$match': {'$and': [ { 'xId' : ?0 },{'pDay': { '$gte': ?1 } },{'pDay': { '$lte': ?2 } }, ] } }",
        "{$group: { _id: $pDay, abcs: { $addToSet : $$ROOT }}}",
        "{'$sort': {'x2': 1,'x3': 1}}",
        "{'$limit': ?4}",
        "{'$skip': ?5}"
})
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/